# Where, or how, can I programmatically get a complete history of the major cryptocurrencies?

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, bitcoin, explorer-api

I would like to programmatically get a complete list of the historical:

- Number of transactions
- Average Transaction Fee
- Hashrate
- Mining Profitability
- Difficulty
- Block Time
- Block Size

related to the major cryptocurrencies

Answer (score 0):

There is https://bitinfocharts.com/ although I see not API so you would have to crawl it.
If you are missing coins you would need to create a list of these and look up their individual block explorers. Usually every coin has one but I do not know of a single place where all the hundreds of coins stats are kept.

Comment: I am also very interested in finding a good index of these but this is quite a lot of info to gather.